# How can I set a value for a string in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

In my current class I have a field that looks like this:

class

```
 @Inject
 @ConfigValue(key = ConfigProperties.ADDRESS)
 private String address;
```

ConfigProperties

```
  public static final String ADDRESS = //
        "42 Rue Cadet, 75009 Paris";
```

I have a method:

```
 ...... 
 private boolean isValidAddress() {
    if(address != null && address.equals("42 Rue Cadet, 75009 Paris")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 } 
 ......
```

I want to creat a unit test that verify the isValidAddress() method but I don't know how to set the address.

For exemple: I want to test with this address = "23 Rue Luvru, 75045 Paris". 
   I was thinking to mock the ConfigProperties but I don't have any method in ConfigProperties where I could set the value for address.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can set `address` via reflection or make it protected rather than private, but you'll also have trouble calling `isValidAddress` from your test, since it's private, unless you mean you'll call some other part of the public API of the class which uses `isValidAddress`. Normally you only unit test the public API, not private helper methods.

Comment: @DavidConrad, yes I am using `isValidAddress` in another method. Via reflection do you mean using setter and getter ?

Comment: No, by reflection I mean accessing the field via `java.reflect.Field` and setting its value directly.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem, and using reflection to solve the problem as many people suggest is quite cumbersome... so we wrote a JUnit5 Extension to solve this exact problem:

https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

What it does is inject values into your class under test that have the same key names in a Map that you provide.

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class, InjectMapExtension.class })
public class MyControllerTest {
 @InjectMocks
 private MyController myController;
 @Mock
 private Logger log;
 @Mock
 private Authenticator auther;
 @InjectionMap
 private Map<String, Object> injectionMap = new HashMap<>();

 @BeforeEach
 public void beforeEach() throws Exception {
  injectionMap.put("securityEnabled", Boolean.TRUE);
 }

 @AfterEach
 public void afterEach() throws Exception {
  injectionMap.clear();
 }

 public void testDoSomething_secEnabled() throws Exception {
  myController.doSomething();
 }
```